# Send packet from server to specific client using saved client ip address?

Tags: c++, client-server, boost-asio, ip-address

Lets say for example that I'm using the async server and a client connects to the server. The server saves the clients' information regarding its ip address, port#, etc. and stores it in a database for future use, is there a way to take the clients information and store it. I tried looking at the [socket](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html) implementation but I couldn't find any way to determine the ip-address the client used to send data from. I also wondered what happens if I used localhost (e.g. 127.0.0.1) to test multiple clients on the same machine and would that conflict somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`socket::remote_endpoint()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/remote_endpoint/overload1.html) method to get the endpoint of a connected socket. Multiple clients connected from the same remote host will use a different port number, as an example `127.0.0.1:1234` and `127.0.0.1:5678`.

Comment: So I get this part `boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = socket.remote_endpoint(ec);` but then how do I use the `endpoint` object to send packets to the client? For an async server by the way.

Comment: Actually looking at the code I realize I just need to send a packet to the `endpoint.address` and `endpoint.port` but boost `write` and `send` do not have any parameter for either the ip or the port?

Comment: @lost tcp sockets operate on streams of data, not packets. You send data using a socket, not an endpoint. I suggest asking a new question if your understanding is not clear.

Comment: Alright I started it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006894/c-boost-asio-sending-packets-to-a-client-given-the-endpoint-object